# Android Studio Gradle sync failed CreateProcess error=2

Tags: android, gradle, synchronization, createprocess

I got a problem with Android Studio when I want to start a new project 
I search everywhere online and couldnt find an answer for it

I get this error

[image: i get this error]

> Gradle sync failed: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
>               Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (9s 679ms)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problem with JDK location. Goto Files->Other Settings->Default Project Structure and make sure that yout JDK location is correct.

Comment: I downloaded JDK because my Android Studio pointed to JRE, so now the jdk location is good for sure but still the same error message

Comment: are you using git in project?

Comment: I dont know why, but Android Studio wont let me to change the directory path, after I click "OK" it not actually changed the directory .. because when I go the the "Other Setting" again it pointed what it was in the beginning  .. and no I dont use git or something just started new Porject normally(Default Settings)

Answer (score 0):

> Goto Files->Other Settings->Default Project Structure.
>
> Under Platform Settings Select Android sdk...under JDK location change C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk*** to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk***

Comment: Its look good but it point on the jre, I dont have JDK their is any different? C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre